# Why don't the links in my Chrome Extension Open?

Tags: google-chrome, hyperlink, google-chrome-extension

I've got a simple little Chrome Extension that displays Links to some RSS Feed Items.

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/kphnebohimlmflbecpghgbclhobnphnm?hl=en-GB

However, clicking the links does nothing. What am I doing wrong.

I'm sure it's very simple. Am I missing any Permissions from my Manifest file?

Comment: Please ignore this. I didn't realise I had to do target _Blank lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also call `chrome.tabs.create` (requires `tabs` permission in your manifest file).